# Loss of edge pixels when displaying clipped rasters

Tags: qgis-2.2

I am looking for tips to clip properly and cleanly 1 raster in 4 rasters without loss of pixels at the edge.

I am using QGIS Valmeria. I have a raster named 'A' representing the Percent of trees cover (PTC), from 1000m elevation to 4000m elevation. From it, I want to get 4 rasters representing the PTC at 1000m, 2000m, 3000m and 4000m elevation.

So using polygons of the four elevations, i clipped the raster 'A' (command raster>extraction>clip). for the rasters obtained, i write '0' for the additional null value (in order to remove the frame around).

But when i display together the four rasters, there is a kind of stream of 1 or 2 pixels large between the rasters displayed. It looks like the pixels at the edge of the clipped rasters are missing. The pixels lose represent PTC data from 0 to 100%.
[image]